# Removing rows from a data.frame with -grep removes all rows if no matches are found (-- how to prevent this?)

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a data frame that gets updated frequently, and there are some rows that need to be removed from it if certain strings are found in them.  I have done that previously using -grep to remove the rows containing the string in question, eg:

```
dataframe[-grep('some string', dataframe$column),]
```

However, at times that string doesn't appear in the dataframe, in which case the -grep is returning an empty dataframe.  Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
> test.df<-data.frame(number=c(1:10), letter=letters[1:10])

> test.df
   number letter
1       1      a
2       2      b
3       3      c
4       4      d
5       5      e
6       6      f
7       7      g
8       8      h
9       9      i
10     10      j

> test.df[-grep('h', test.df$letter),]
   number letter
1       1      a
2       2      b
3       3      c
4       4      d
5       5      e
6       6      f
7       7      g
9       9      i
10     10      j

> test.df[-grep('k', test.df$letter),]
[1] number letter
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I could wrap the 'test.df[-grep...' in an 'if' test to check if the search string is found prior to removing it, eg:

```
if(any(grepl('k',test.df$letter))){test.df<-test.df[-grep('k', test.df$letter),]}
```

...but it seems to me that this should be implicit in the -grep command.  Is there a better (more efficient) way to accomplish row removal that doesn't threaten to remove all my data if the search string is absent from the data frame?

Comment: Your example code does not assign the results of the `grep` back to `test.df`, so no rows are being removed from it - the message is just telling you that no matching rows were found.

Comment: Yes, that was just for example purposes, to show what -grep was doing.  In my actual code I am assigning the data back to the dataframe.

Comment: we can also use `stringr` functions , something like `test.df2 <- test.df[!str_detect(test.df$letter,'z'),]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `grepl` you could do:

```r
test.df <- data.frame(number = c(1:10), letter = letters[1:10])

test.df[!grepl("h", test.df$letter), ]
#>    number letter
#> 1       1      a
#> 2       2      b
#> 3       3      c
#> 4       4      d
#> 5       5      e
#> 6       6      f
#> 7       7      g
#> 9       9      i
#> 10     10      j

test.df[!grepl("k", test.df$letter), ]
#>    number letter
#> 1       1      a
#> 2       2      b
#> 3       3      c
#> 4       4      d
#> 5       5      e
#> 6       6      f
#> 7       7      g
#> 8       8      h
#> 9       9      i
#> 10     10      j
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Now I'm wondering if there is any scenario where -grep is actually better than !grepl  .. ?

Comment: For subsetting I would go for grepl. But in cases where you actually need the indidces or the values of the matches go for `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `-` when subsetting, in `grep` `invert` could be used.

```
test.df[grep('k', test.df$letter, invert=TRUE),]
#   number letter
#1       1      a
#2       2      b
#3       3      c
#4       4      d
#5       5      e
#6       6      f
#7       7      g
#8       8      h
#9       9      i
#10     10      j

test.df[grep('h', test.df$letter, invert=TRUE),]
#   number letter
#1       1      a
#2       2      b
#3       3      c
#4       4      d
#5       5      e
#6       6      f
#7       7      g
#9       9      i
#10     10      j
```

---

In this case it looks like that the whole sting should be matched, where an alternative would be to use `==` or `!=`.

```
test.df[test.df$letter != "k",]
test.df[test.df$letter != "h",]
```